# Function name mangling. _cdecl convention

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, dll, dllexport

This question is about name mangling while exporting functions in DLLs. Microsoft on this link says that an

> Underscore character (_) is prefixed to names, except when exporting __cdecl functions that use C linkage.

link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zkwh89ks.aspx

The question is: what should be happening if I export a _cdecl function using C linkage? Is there any standartized behaviour for this case?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

extern "C" void Foo(int) will result in Foo. C linkage just exports functions without mangeling using their function name

Comment: Can you please link a document or something where this is stated? Because msdn says:

> For C functions or functions that are declared as extern "C", this includes platform-specific decoration that's based on the calling convention.

So that means that there is a decoration. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y1sfaz2.aspx

Comment: https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr020.htm under Name Mangeling (C++ only) To prevent the C++ compiler from mangling the name of a function, you can apply the extern "C" linkage specifier to the declaration or declarations, as shown in the following example:

extern "C" {
   int f1(int);
   int f2(int);
   int f3(int);
};

This declaration tells the compiler that references to the functions f1, f2, and f3 should not be mangled.

Comment: it might be that visual studio adds underscores or the like to the name for calling conventions different than cdecl but atleast for cdecl only the name is used

Comment: But that just proves the "platform-specific" thesis.

Comment: http://agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf page 41 i think this will help you. seems like extern "C" doesnt completely remove name mangeling