# 32 bit mingw not finding any symbols

Tags: assembly, gcc, mingw, ld

I am trying to build a Windows DLL using a MinGW compiler on Linux. Minimum (non-working) code example looks like this:

```
.global mycode
.text

mycode:
   call cos
```

(I know that that code is nonsense, it's just an example).

When I try to compile this for 64-bit Windows using the following command, I get no errors and it outputs a 64-bit DLL:

```
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -fPIC -shared -masm=intel -o test.dll test.s -lm
```

When I try the same thing for 32-bit Windows, I get errors:

```
$ i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -fPIC -m32 -shared -masm=intel -o test32.dll test.s -lm
/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot export mycode: symbol not found
/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ld: /tmp/ccb5JLMY.o:fake:(.text+0x1): undefined reference to `cos'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I missing? Why is the linker unable to export `mycode` even though it's defined in the code, and why does it fail to find `cos` even though I am linking to `libm`?

Comment: I don't think `-lm` does anything on Windows, the math functions are part of the CRT anyways. But you probably need `_cos` [instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21277484/1983398).

Comment: Okay, using `_cos` instead of `cos` got rid of that error, thanks. But it still displays "cannot export X" for all the functions present in my code.

Comment: Looks like you need the underscore also for the exported functions, so try `_mycode`.

Comment: Windows 32-bit code decorates C names with a leading underscore to make asm symbol names, 64-bit doesn't.